# How to fetch below output using SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Team:

```
1 India
2 Pakistan
3 Srilanka
4 Australia
```

Output:

```
1 Pakistan VS India 
2 Srilanka VS Pakistan 
3 Srilanka VS India
4 Australia VS Srilanka
5 Australia VS Pakistan 
6 Australia VS India
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. You need to tag the DBMS you are working with. I doubt you have both mysql and sql-server. Also we need to have some details to help. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for this.  Assume your original table is called '#temp2'

```
   select a.string+' VS '+b.string from #temp2 a cross join #temp2 b
    where a.string = 'Australia' and a.string<>b.string
    union all
     select a.string+' VS '+b.string from #temp2 a cross join #temp2 b
    where a.string = 'Srilanka' and a.string<>b.string and b.string not in (Select a.string from #temp2 a cross join #temp2 b
    where a.string = 'Australia')
    union all
     select a.string+' VS '+b.string from #temp2 a cross join #temp2 b
    where a.string = 'Pakistan' and a.string<>b.string 
    and b.string not in (Select a.string from #temp2 a cross join #temp2 b
    where a.string = 'Australia')
    and b.string not in (Select a.string from #temp2 a cross join #temp2 b
    where a.string = 'Srilanka')
```

Comment: Why not do this as a single query and drop all those where predicates. For heaven sake this is more effort than typing it out manually.

Comment: Thanks for the help daniel

Answer (score 0):

this works:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Order By (Select null)),t2.Name +' VS '+ t1.Name 
FROM Team t1
JOIN Team t2 on t2.id>t1.Id
order by t2.Id,t1.Id desc
```